# Doctrine 2 INNER JOIN com Subquery

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, doctrine, doctrine-2

Estou migrando minhas consultas para *doctrine* usando o *QueryBuilder*. E possuo uma consulta com *inner join* com uma *subquery*, gostaria de saber como fazer isso usando *doctrine*.

```
        SELECT p.*
        FROM produtos p
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT e.*, d.id_deposito, d.quantidade, d.qtde_temp, d.valor_produto, d.valor, d.valor_representante_produto, d.valor_representante, d.id_erp
            FROM produtos_estoque e
            INNER JOIN depositos_produtos_estoque d ON e.id_estoque = d.id_estoque
            WHERE e.inativo = '0' AND e.excluido = '0' AND d.excluido = '0' AND d.id_deposito = '1' AND d.inativo = 0 AND d.valor != '0.00'
        ) e ON p.id_produto = e.id_produto
```

Transferindo para *doctrine* pensei na seguinte solução, porém não funciona da seguinte forma, já pesquisei porém não encontrei uma solução que funcionasse no *doctrine 2*.

```
        $qb_estoque = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb_estoque->select("e, d1.id_deposito, d.quantidade, d.qtde_temp, d.valor_produto, d.valor, d.valor_representante_produto, d.valor_representante, d.id_erp")
            ->from(\model\entity\Produtos_estoque::get_class_name(), "e")
            ->innerJoin(\model\entity\Depositos_produtos_estoque::get_class_name(), "d", Join::WITH, "e.id_estoque = d.produtos_estoque")
            ->innerJoin("d.depositos", "d1")
            ->where($qb_estoque->expr()->andX(
                $qb_estoque->expr()->eq("e.inativo", 0),
                $qb_estoque->expr()->eq("e.excluido", 0),
                $qb_estoque->expr()->eq("d.inativo", 0),
                $qb_estoque->expr()->eq("d.excluido", 0),
                $qb_estoque->expr()->eq("d1.id_deposito", 1),
                $qb_estoque->expr()->neq("d.valor", 0)
            ));

        $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select("p")
            ->from(\model\entity\Produtos::get_class_name(), "p")
            ->innerJoin(sprintf("(%s)", $qb_estoque->getQuery()->getSQL()).")", 'e', Join::WITH, 'p.id_produto = e.produtos');
```

***Obs.: Sim, dever ser feito usando subquery, pois o restante da consulta precisa de usar informações que estão contidas na subquery.***

Comment: Você pode expor o codigo das entities utilizadas na consulta?

Comment: Se você puder também fazer um pequeno esquema de como as suas tabelas estão relacionadas. E qual versão do php você está utilizando?

Answer (score 0):

Avaliando a sua consulta, não consigo visualizar um motivo para utilizar a subQuery. Os dados que estão contidos na subQuery são apenas a junção com filtro dos demais dados. Portanto, esta consulta deve trazer as entidades necessárias:

```
$qb
  ->select("p")
  ->from(\model\entity\Produtos::get_class_name(), "p")
  ->join('p.estoques', 'estoques')
   -join('estoques.depositos', 'depositos')
  ->where('estoques.inativo = :estoqueInativo')
  ->andWhere('estoques.excluido = :estoqueExcluido')
  ->andWhere('depositos.excluido = :depositoExcluido')
  ->andWhere('depositos.id = :idDeposito')
  ->andWhere('depositos.inativo = :depositoInativo')
  ->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('depositos.valor', '0'))
  ->setParameter('estoqueInativo', false)
  ->setParameter('estoqueExcluido', false)
  ->setParameter('depositoExcluido', false)
  ->setParameter('idDeposito', 1)
  ->setParameter('depositoInativo', false);
```

O que realmente pode haver de problema aqui é o caso de você não ter relacionado corretamente as entidades. Para este caso em especifico, você precisa que a entidade `Produto` esteja relacionada com a entidade `Estoque`.

Um exemplo de como as três entidades podem ser construidas. Produto:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Produto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Estoque", mappedBy="produto")
     */
    private $estoques;
}
```

Estoque:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Estoque
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Produto", inversedBy="estoques")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $produto;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Deposito", mappedBy="estoque")
     */
    private $depositos;
}
```

Deposito

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class Deposito
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Estoque", inversedBy="depositos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $estoque;
}
```